# Postgres - autovacuum doesn't end - should I run a manual vacuum?

Tags: postgresql, postgres-9.6, autovacuum

I have a table that had 80K writes per minute..
I did a change that reduce the load on this table (now it's 40K writes per minute).

Currently I can see that there's an autovacuum that has been running for more than 3 days(!) and my table (autovacuum: VACUUM ANALYZE table (to prevent wraparound)

Should I run "Vacuum table" manually? Will it end as long as I'm not stopping the writes ?

Should I terminate this "autovacuum" process?

Any advice will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Run the `VACUUM` manually for now. If the transaction wrap-around vacuum doesn't finish in time, your server will go down.

Set `autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay` to 0 for this table using `ALTER TABLE`. Then autovacuum will process that table as fast as it can.